# store fread() in char instead memory buffer

Tags: visual-c++

im new in c++ and i've some noob questions:

I've trying to do a program that read an ISO file and return some info like size, block size, blocks...

My fist question is about fread, and how to store readed info into a char variable instead a buffer, because if i store in buffer when i return the string the program show the text with 4 'ý' characters.

if i use for example:

```
char *systemID = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*32);
fread(systemID, 1, 8, infile);
```

then works with the 4 'ý' at end, but if i use:

```
systemID = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*32);
fread(systemID, 1, 8, infile);
```

then the program crash...
How i can store that fread info into char variable?, or how i can avoid the last 'ý' charactes?

Another question that i've: Someone have info about ISO image and how to get a list of files inside a ISO in c++. I want to do it without run another programs, because with 7Zip and others i can get a list of files but i want to do an standalone program.

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that strings in C (and C++) needs to be terminated. The `fread` function returns the number of items that were read, and you can use that as an index to terminate your string:

```
char *systemID = malloc(32);
size_t nread = fread(systemID, 1, 8, infile);
if (nread > 0)
    systemID[nread] = '\0';  /* Terminate string */
else
{
    /* Handle end-of-file or error */
}
```